# Tiling rectangle with fixed size tiles

Tags: algorithm, math

I have been struggling with finding a convenient solution for the following problem:

Suppose we have a wall of a given size and 4 types of tiles of sizes 4 x 2, 2 x 2, 2 x 1, 1 x 1. There are certain rectangular regions inside the perimeter of the wall which can not be tiled (i.e. holes). There is also a special type of tile which has a variable dimension A x B with A < 1. This is used to pad the tiling to the margin of the rectangle, if needed.

Find a tiling of the wall which respects the following constraints:

1. Tiles of the same size can not be placed one below the other, with the same alignment (i.e. tiles appearing on a row below have to be shifted such that there is no gap which looks like a cross between adjoining tiles of the same size)
2. A minimum number of tiles is used
3. Tiles which exceed the boundaries of the rectangle will be trimmed to the margin; the incomplete tile thus produced will be broken in smaller tiles; this could possibly involve the use of a special tile which should always sit next to the margin of the rectangle or the margin of a hole, wherever the situation might arise

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. I've looked into algorithms for solving this using domino tiling but most don't seem to care that the tiling process can not produce gaps which look like a cross where tiles meet. Also, to me the problem seems a bit different as there are more types of tiles and it also seems that the rectangle does not have to be exactly filled (it is possible for small spaces to remain near the margins which will be filled using special tiles)
2. I've tried to generate all possible tilings using a branch and bound technique with state node pruning so that only those states where tiles which do not break the constraints are added will be explored, but this is definitely not scalable.
3. I've also looked into packing algorithms but to my knowledge, this might lead to a certain tiling where there are small untiled spaces which can remain inside the premises of the wall.

It might be possible that I've overlooked something, or not had enough insight while exploring the above techniques.

With all these being said, do you guys have any hints or suggestions on a way to approach this which yields results?

[This is an example of a tiling which respects constraints 1 and 3, but is not optimal](http://www.flickr.com/photos/69133050@N07/6287086752/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the optimal tiling, or are you willing to settle for "pretty good"? Finding the optimal solution is likely exceedingly hard. Intuitively, I would suggest the following heuristic:

```
1. Pretend there are no holes in the wall, tile with large tiles.

2. Remove all tiles which intersect with holes.

3. current_size = largest

4. For each empty space: tile as much as possible with current_size

5. current_size = the size just below current_size

6. return to 4
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is complexity in filling in the remaining size. One needs to find the first placement so that no crosses(+) are formed. This depends on the way you've done your first tiling, of course. There might be situations where such a tiling is not possible because of the way you've made your first tiling. There are also situations where holes are close to each other which makes you consider them as a joint case which increases the search space.